# an ambiguous wh-question with embedded clause

Tags: syntax

how is this question ambiguous?

Why did Bill say that John was fired?

to me it has one meaning. it asks about the reason for which bill said that john was fired! if it has another meaning that I cant see. please explain it to me! how can one structure have two meanings!!!

Comment: This question is language-specific, so it can be better answered on English.SE or ELL.SE. Also, it's actually a request to build a syntax tree with no own effort to answer. Try using some online parsers, like [this one](http://erg.delph-in.net/logon). Trying your sentence, it shows at least three non-trivial parsings: (1) "why" as an adverb; (2) "that John" as NP; (3) "was fired" as VP or PP.

Comment: @bytebuster I can't see any syntax tree request and the question hasn't been edited at all ...

Answer (score 3):

The sentence

- *Why did Bill say that John was fired?*

has, besides the meanings mentioned by @bytebuster in a comment, two quite different senses.

That's because *why* asks for a reason, and in this sentence that reason can be  **either**

1. the reason why Bill said the sentence "John was fired" (say, Bill wanted me to know),
   **or**
2. the reason why John was fired (say, John lit a firecracker under Bill's desk).

The rule of *Wh*-Question Formation is not a cyclic rule, limited in its effects to constituents in the neighborhood of a single clause, and therefore *Wh*-Question Formation can move a *wh*-word from anywhere in the question to the beginning. 
In this case, it has a choice of moving one from the main clause or one from a subordinate clause.

Comment: Ah **that** was the 4th meaning the Web app returned, but I failed to comprehend!

Comment: I don't understand the last part of the answer.  What does "single clause" mean?  Why are cyclic rules limited to "a single clause"?

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for the explanation